# Magento 2 CMS Page getList() repository methods does not return expected object

Tags: magento2

I need to delete all CMS pages.

Here is the code:

```
namespace Soon\Core\Setup;

use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;

class Cms
{
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaInterface
     */
    private $searchCriteria;
    /**
     * @var PageRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $cmsPageRepository;

    /**
     * Cms constructor.
     * @param SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @param PageRepositoryInterface $cmsPageRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria,
        PageRepositoryInterface $cmsPageRepository
    )
    {
        $this->searchCriteria = $searchCriteria;
        $this->cmsPageRepository = $cmsPageRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Delete all existing CMS pages
     */
    public function cleanCmsPages()
    {
        $cmsPageCollection = $this->cmsPageRepository
            ->getList($this->searchCriteria)
            ->getItems();

        foreach ($cmsPageCollection as $cmsPage) {
            $this->cmsPageRepository->delete($cmsPage);
        }
    }
}
```

So, calling `\Soon\Core\Setup\Cms::cleanCmsPages` should delete all CMS pages.

But when doing so, I get this error:

`Argument 1 passed to Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository::delete() must implement interface Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface, array given`

So I dumped the `$cmsPage` used in my `foreach ($cmsPageCollection as $cmsPage)` and it appears that, indeed, `$cmsPage` is an array.

I digged into the code:

`\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface::getList` is implemented by `\Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository::getList`.

Then in `\Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository::getList`, we can see this bit of code:

```
            $pages[] = $this->dataObjectProcessor->buildOutputDataArray(
                $pageData,
                'Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface'
            );
        }
        $searchResults->setItems($pages);
```

If I am correct, this code creates an array that populates the `$pages` array.
So this code may explain why `$cmsPage` is an array!

**BUT...**

By reading `@return` statement of `\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface::getList`, we can see `@return \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageSearchResultsInterface`.

And, then by reading the `@return` statement from `\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageSearchResultsInterface::getItems`, we can see `\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface[]`!

So the `$cmsPage` in my `foreach` loop should be an implementation of `\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface` which then can be passed properly to `\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface::delete`.

Who's wrong?

1. Me who cannot read / understand @api comments and code properly
2. Magento who whether does not give the right comment in their @api classes... or does not implements the interface as it should.

This analysis is for the CMS Page API but also applies to the CMS *Block* API.

Comment: It looks as bug, someone reported it recently: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7140

Answer (score 2):

You can create bug issue on github if you want. But more faster way for you is to use resource model or if you want use this repository method deleteById() where you can pass id of entity.

vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/PageRepository.php

```
public function deleteById($pageId)
{
    return $this->delete($this->getById($pageId));
}
```

Repositories is not for bulk operation, this affect performance.